# I can't download anything on 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, dpkg, dependencies

When I try to download anything at all through the terminal on 16.04, it doesn't finish something as I do this command: `sudo apt-get install kdenlive`. It then tells me `Unmet Dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).` But then when I try `apt-get -f install` it says,

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What does this mean? I think it means root or moderator of the computer, but I am moderator of the computer already. Please tell me what I can do :(

Comment: You need to run it as `sudo apt-get -f install`, note the use of `sudo`, which will allow root access.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have another update application open: eg Synaptic, Software Updater, Ubuntu Software, another terminal. Then, as @Dave Sha points out, try using `sudo apt-get -f install`.